# Filter lines from file using stopwords in python

Tags: python

I have a text file with some lines of text. I need to filter out all the lines that start with lowercase letters and print only lines that start with uppercase. How do I do this in Python ?

I have tried this:

```
filtercase =('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

out = []

ins = open("data.txt","r")
for line in ins:
   for k in filtercase:
      if(not(line.startswith(k))):
           out.append(line)
```

This will still print lines if they start with any lowercase letter other than 'a' . I am not sure how to change the code to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

EDITED:
I have more stopword lists like these which I need to apply on the lines. So its not just a case of upper or lower case.

Comment: Is the stopword always a single letter ? Or can it be a full word ?

Comment: It can be word of any size. This was just one such filter example I gave

Answer (score 2):

Your original code iterates through every single letter in filtercase. If, for each letter, the line DOESN'T start with it, you append to your out list. But clearly, every single line would be appended multiple times, since for a line to NOT be appended to `out`, it must start with `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and every single letter in your filter list.

Rather, you need to iterate through `filtercase`, and need to find one instance of `k` where `line.startswith(k)` is true. If `line.startswith` any phrase in `filtercase`, don't append it; but if it successfully iterates through the entire list without starting with any of its elements, append.

Python's for-else syntax is very useful for checking through a list of elements:

```
out = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as ins:
    for line in ins:
        for k in filtercase:
            if line.startswith(k): # If line starts with any of the filter words
                break # Else block isn't executed.
        else: # Line doesn't start with filter word, append to message
            out.append(line)
```

Comment: Or how about `.isupper()` instead of `not islower()`?

Comment: How do i do it if I have random stopwords and I need to remove lines that have  either of these stopwords ?

Comment: @275365 that would've made sense. Haha

Comment: @jmu303 This would append the line as many times as the number of words in the filtercase right ? How do I keep to one copy.

Comment: No. This will append either once or never.

Comment: Basically: Iterate through every phrase in filtercase. If the line in question starts with a phrase you don't want, then `break`. You exit out of the loop, and the `out.append(line)` in the `else` block is never executed. If you end up iterating through the entire list of filtercase and the line never starts with a prohibited phrase, the `else` block is executed. `out.append(line)` is executed, then the loop moves on to the next line in the file.

Comment: You are right! My bad I combined the 'else' with the 'if' there. Thanks @jmu303

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as ins:
    out = filter(lambda line: [sw for sw in filtercase if line.startswith(sw)] == [], ins.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses regexp, and will only match lines that starts with a capital letter, and that does not contain any of the words in stopword. Note that e.g. the line `'messenger'` will not be matched if one of the stopwords are `'me'`.

```
import re

out = []
stopwords = ['no', 'please', 'dont']
lower = re.compile('^[a-z]')
upper = re.compile('^[A-Z]')
with open('data.txt') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if (not lower.match(line) and
            not any(word in line for word in stopwords)) \
            and upper.match(line):
           out.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
fp = open("text.txt","r")
out = []
yesYes = xrange(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)
noNo = xrange(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)
for line in fp:
    if len(line)>0 and ord(line[0]) in yesYes and ord(line[0]) not in noNo:
         out.append(line)
```

Or in a single line-

```
out = [line for line in open("text.txt","r") if len(line)>0 and ord(line[0]) in xrange(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1) and ord(line[0]) not in xrange(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for lowercase can be really fast, by putting using the ascii code range for the lowercase letters. Once thus optimized, you could put all stop words in a set (for faster lookup). This yields the following code:

```
lowers = (ord('a'), ord('z'))
stopWords = set((i.lower() for i in "firstWord anotherWord".split()))
out = []
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if lowers[0] <= line[0] <= lowers[1]:
            continue
        if line.split(None, 1)[0].lower() in stopWords:
            continue
        out.append(line)
```